# CSS 3 column float and negative margin liquid layout

Tags: html, css, margin

I just stumbled upon some problem while I was teaching CSS layout using `float` and negative `margin`.

I came up with this simple semantic HTML structure (main contents first, other relatively less important contents after).

3 column layout that has 2 fixed width column on both sides and 1 fluid column on center.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">main content</div>
    <div id="nav">navigation</div>
    <div id="extra">extra</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 120px 0 200px;
  }
  #main, #extra, #nav {
    float: left;
  }
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  #nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    left: -200px;
  }
  #extra {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: -120px;
  }
  #footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

This layout works fine even on IE8 :)

http://codepen.io/nori2tae/pen/rFLJb?editors=110

However, the part I don't quite understand why `div#extra` is sitting right next to `div#main` by setting `margin-right: -120px;` on `div#extra`.

But `margin-left: -120px;` does not work...

Can somebody please explain why this happening?

Comment: Semantic HTML would be using the `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<footer>` etc tags for the relevant `<section>`s ;-)

Comment: ...and `<main>` & `<aside>`. Plus I'm not sure why you need to float the items and then use negative margin in the first place.

Comment: True. I made this just to show my colleagues how float and negative-margin works. I will change TAGs later on.

Comment: I know there are plenty ways to archive 3 column layout. I thought this is one way... I just wonder and wanna know why negative-margin-right works like this.

Comment: `margin-left:-120px` moves the div 120px to left, since they are both floated it'll cut into the previous div. `margin-right:-120px` gives the div a width+padding+margin = 0 so it gets pushed off the side, if you added 1px to width,margin or padding it will go below.

Comment: plus I wouldn't be using floats to achieve this layout anymore - it would be much easier to use `display:table` if you are only supporting ie8 and up

Comment: @serakfalcon I didn't know the div has negative-right which width would be 0. That explains a lot to me.
div#extra looks like it has width but doesn't in the world of float. hard to expalin...

Comment: @Pete Yes. I love using `display: table` to line elements side by side. But do you have to put `div#main` in 2nd place (after `div#nav`) ? Or maybe I shouldn't worry too much about what contents appear first in the HTML...

Comment: Most sites usually have their main nav appearing before the content anyway.  If you are worried about accessibility, then you should just add a skip nav button (can be hidden off the screen) that will take you straight to your content.  Also if the nav isn't specific to the page / content there is no real reason to put it after the content

Comment: to answer your question - margin-right works as you have set that right padding on your wrapper so it is margined into that padded space (as all your elements are float left and your main takes up the whole width), Margin-left would only margin it back into the main div area as it will be sat on the right of the main div.  Your nav is able to go to the left as you have added a margin-left of 100% - making it move the width of the main div, then a left of 200px making it move into the left padding of the wrapper